# Changed name in Google but still old name in Google

Tags: google-plus, privacy

I changed my name in Google for privacy reasons but if I search for my real name in Google I see the following result:

```
Real Name - Google+
from Fake Name
Fake Name hasn't shared anything with you...
```

That's even worse... now everybody can see what my fake name on the internet is.  Is there a way to change this? I don't want my Google+ to appear in the search results at all.

I changed the name 1 month ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of places in the Googleverse where a name is attached to your account. They are generally the same, but can get out of sync and you may need to change them manually.

1. Gmail "Send mail as:" - From Gmail, choose "Settings", then "[Accounts and Import](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts)", then click the "edit info" link for your main (or only) "Send mail as:" entry
2. "[Personal info & Privacy](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy)" in "My Account" - Go to myaccount.google.com, then "Personal info & Privacy" and the "Your personal info" section. You can change your name and nickname there
3. Your Google "[About Me](https://aboutme.google.com)" page - this appears to control what is displayed on Google+

Make sure all of those are showing the name you want.

As for being in search results, you need to go to your [Google+ settings](https://plus.google.com/settings) and turn off "Help others discover my profile in search results" under "Profile". ([Google Support](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1151728))