# How to get rid of Google profile photo?

Tags: google-account-profile

I deleted my Google+ profile photo, but I still see it on the top-right corner of Google.

However, when I click it, the popup (which says "My Account", "Add Account", etc.) doesn't have my profile photo—and it used to have it before I had deleted my photo.

Clearly my photo has been only partially removed; how can I remove it entirely?

Comment: [This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106593/354) is for profile name, but it may also be useful for tracking down profile photo(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems just waiting a few days allows it to get fixed. I think it had been probably cached somewhere on the browser.